# Emacs not automatically adding / when finding paths in Dired

Tags: dired

When I move or copy a file in Emacs `dired` I am prompted to choose a directory. If it is a directory I have just created, `dired` will guess it when I invoke `dired-do-rename` and then hit `tab`. I have noticed however that though it correctly guesses the name of the new directory, it does not automatically add `/` after the directory name unless I invoke `tab` again. I would prefer it to add the `/` with the first `tab` invocation.

This is what I have now in place in terms of Completion
Styles:

```
basic
partial-completion
emacs22.
```

Other options I see include `emacs21, substring, flex, initials`, and `shorthand`.

I am unsure of changing these styles would make any difference.

I am currently running Emacs 28.2 in Windows 11

Comment: I don't see that - for me a slash (/) is appended. Can you provide a step-by-step recipe, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? What is your value of option `dired-dwim-target`, for example? (And I assume you mean when multiple files are marked for renaming/moving. But please specify this too.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this has anything to do with `completion-styles` - the default directory you see should be provided by `dired-do-rename` itself, which means it's done by `dired-do-create-files`, using `dired-dwim-target-directory` (which see).

Comment: I tested this behaviour with `emacs-Q` and I still am not getting a slash. Yes, I mean when multiple files are marked for renaming/moving.

Comment: Please post a step-by-step recipe to repro it, starting from `emacs - Q`. That will likely help others help you. Say, at each step, what you see and what you expected to see instead. And maybe post what `M-x emacs-version` shows. And maybe try with different, simpler `completion-styles`, and see if that has any effect (I don't think it will - I think `completion-styles` is a red herring here, but worth finding out).

Comment: I am currently testing the behaviour. Will revert when I have clarity.